# hide composer vendor folder that's inside docroot

Tags: php, apache, composer-php

We have setup about two dozen internal web applications. Now years later, I'd like to start using packages from external sources and installing items by using Composer which manages packages. I've never needed it before but would like to try adding some extra functionality to these sites.

The problem is none of these internal websites were setup with /project/public_html/ structures. The document root is the main directory inside WAMP.

So the DOCUMENT_ROOT directories look something like this:

```
c:\wamp64\www\my-site1\
c:\wamp64\www\my-site2\
c:\wamp64\www\my-site3\
```

Each project is different and might require different php packages. I'd like to be able to use Composer to manage the packages.

When you run Composer is creates a *vendor* folder. I know that good practice dictates that we should put it in a structure like this:

```
C:\wamp64\www\my-project1\vendor  //for vendor code
C:\wamp64\www\my-project1\public_html //for DOCUMENT_ROOT
```

But what I have ended up with is thus:

```
C:\wamp64\www\my-site1\vendor  //for vendor code specific to site1
C:\wamp64\www\my-site2\vendor  //for vendor code specific to site2
```

**Can I use apache rewrite rules to hide this vendor folder and all child folders from the public web?** Idea being it would deny a user that types in http://my-site1/vendor/somevendor/somefile.php but would still allow my scripts to require or include and use the files in that directory when needed.

Alternatively can I put vendor here:

```
 C:\wamp64\www\vendor
```

and then somehow only include the vendor projects that I want? Not all vendor packages to every project, some way to specify which classes or packages I want to use on a per site basis.

Comment: Simple answer: Put it outside of the docroot.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by that? Having a common folder would cause huge problems if different applications use different versions of the same package

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply place a .htaccess file in your vendor folder with:

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
```

Files inside the vendor folder won't be accessible by typing url in a browser but will be available for your scripts.

Comment: What about subfolders in vendor?  like `vendor/library1`  `vendor/library2` etc. I don't want to have to put an .htaccess in each and every one of those child folders.

Comment: @S.Mason yes subdirectories are also protected by the .htacces. Give it a try :)

Comment: Okay great, one thing is that in the order command, there cannot be a space after the comma or there is an Apache error as I found out.  Should be `Order allow,deny` <-no space after comma

Answer (score 8):

You may consider keeping vendors outside of docroot with following files structure:

```
c:\wamp64\www\my-site1\
c:\wamp64\www\my-site2\
c:\wamp64\www\my-site3\
c:\wamp64\www\vendors\my-site1\
c:\wamp64\www\vendors\my-site2\
c:\wamp64\www\vendors\my-site3\
```

Configuring vendor directory in `composer.json`:

```
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "../vendors/my-site1"
},
```

And including autoloader in your `index.php`:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendors/my-site1/autoload.php';
```

---

If you can't change directory for vendors, you may use mod rewrite to disallow access to `vendor` directory. Put this into your main `.htaccess` file (for example to `c:\wamp64\www\my-site1\.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^vendor/(.*)?$ / [F,L]
RewriteRule ^composer\.(lock|json)$ / [F,L]
```

Using `.htaccess` inside of `vendor` directory will also work, bu it is easy to accidentaly delete this file - usually `vendor` directory is not versioned in VCS and many problems with composer are solvable  by "delete `vendor` directory and run `composer install` again" (which will also remove your `.htaccess` and make `vendor` directory accessible from web).

Comment: I'm going to do something like your first idea: `c:\wamp64\www\composer-packages\my-site1\vendors\ ` each site will get its own subfolder in the \composer-packages\ directory. That way it's out of the doc root but still identifiable to the site it belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizing @wizardnx answer, you can update your `composer.json` to add the `.htaccess` file to the `vendor` directory after running `composer install` command as following:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "robmorgan/phinx": "^0.13.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php -r \"file_put_contents('vendor/.htaccess', 'Order allow,deny' . PHP_EOL . 'Deny from all');\""
        ]
    }
}
```